# Safely cache and store personal access tokens

Tags: r, github, access-token

I'm working on a R package that interacts with APIs from GitHub, Google, and Calendly and these services all have tokens. Our package directs the user to create a personal access token, let's say a GitHub PAT, and asks the user to paste the token. Then, we save the token in a variable called token and cache it.

I was wondering what are some best practices to cache (store) these personal access tokens?

Currently, we are saving the tokens as a RDS file and moving it to `inst/extdata/cached_secrets`.

UPDATE:

Here is the code we are using to save the tokens as a RDS file:

```
cache_secrets_folder <- function() {
  list.files(
    pattern = "cached-secrets",
    recursive = TRUE,
    system.file("extdata", package = "metricminer"),
    full.names = TRUE,
    include.dirs = TRUE,
  )
}

if (cache_it == 1) saveRDS(token, file.path(cache_secrets_folder(), "github.RDS"))
```

Comment: It isn't clear whether you are saving those tokens before building the package or later when the user runs it.  If it's later, don't do that.  That directory won't exist in your package after installation, it is likely not writable by users, and it might be shared by several users.  Use existing methods like the `keyring` package provides to save secrets, and put user config data that isn't secret in `tools::R_user_dir()`.

Comment: Later when the user runs it. I've updated the OP with code that saves the tokens as a RDS file.

Comment: I hope you aren't intending to send your package to CRAN -- they won't accept it.

Comment: I'm curious - can you point to CRAN policy that prohibits this?

Comment: " Packages should not write in the user’s home filespace (including clipboards), nor anywhere else on the file system apart from the R session’s temporary directory (or during installation in the location pointed to by TMPDIR: and such usage should be cleaned up). "

Comment: `R_user_dir()` is described as an exception to the above in the next paragraph.  This is from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html .

Comment: I see that `tools::R_user_dir()` is the way to go. Package on CRAN, like [this one](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtoot/vignettes/auth.html), uses it.

Comment: So, what is the difference between the paths returned by `tools::R_user_dir("metricminer")` and `system.file("extdata", package = "metricminer")`. On my Mac, the former returns `/Users/howardbaek/Library/Application Support/org.R-project.R/R/metricminer` and the latter `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/metricminer/extdata`

Comment: And why does CRAN prefer the former path over the latter? Thanks :)

Comment: See my very first comment.